# Computational Complexity of Algorithms

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, computational-complexity

I want to know if the following proposition is correct or not?

> For any integer k, there exists an problem P for which, the minimum possible time complexity of any solution algorithm is $\Omega(n^k)$

Please give me creditable sources such as journal papers, books, etc. about the solution of the above question.

**UPDATE:** By algorithm I mean standard algorithms as discussed in computational complexity. i.e. an algorithm that for any binary encoded input of size n which corresponds to a problem instance, outputs 0 or 1 (or true or false)

Thanks

Comment: Well, that is easy to prove for algorithms - we can just write an alogorithm that stalls for that period of time.  The harder question - is there a problem that can only be solved with an alogithm of that complexity - is probably what you really mean.

Comment: Why do you need a proof from an outside source?  This is simply $k$ nested loops, each iterating $n$ times.

Comment: I corrected my question. That was not what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, look for the Time Hierarchy Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thank you. I didn't expect to find the answer here.